# event is returning undefined, trying to pass it through a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My title seems to not make a lot sense let me try explain.

I have a `GameContainer` component which includes a `ButtonContainer` component.

Now my `ButtonContainer` returns two buttons, X and Y. I am passing a function foo for e.g, now in my Game.js file I pass in the button function as props (`(e) => playGame(e)`). I need the event target id to see if the user pressed X or Y.

The problem I have is when I execute the below code `undefined` is returned.

Game.js

```
const playGame = (e) => {
   console.log(e.target.id);
}
return (
   <GameContainer buttonFn={(e) => playGame(e)} />
);
```

GameContainer.js

```
return (
  <>
    <p>Game name</p>
    <ButtonContainer buttonFn={buttonFn} />
  </>
);
```

ButtonContainer.js

```
return (
  <>
    <button onClick={buttonFn}>X</button>
    <button onClick={buttonFn}>Y</button>
  </>
);
```

I could use redux and then pass the state to my Game.js but I feel like there is an easier way of doing this. e.target.id was working fine in my Game.js but when I decided to split my code into re-usable components and use props it returns undefined.

Any help is appreciated hope my explanation makes sense.

Comment: Pls reproduce this issue here - https://codesandbox.io/s/old-cloud-0deig?file=/src/App.js

Comment: When you click a button will that calls `playtGame` function?

Comment: Where is the undefined error?

Comment: Yes, when pressing the button which invokes the console.log(e.target.id) it returns undefined

Comment: is it undefined or empty string?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hzjvmk check it and correct yourself

Comment: I'll try the codebox by @UKS , the stackblitz is the same as it. And I will report back thanks guys

Comment: I forgot to add the value attributes to the button... please post a comment @UKS so I can accept your answer since you were first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `value` and `id` for the button.

```
export default function App() {
  const playGame = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.id);
  };
  return <GameContainer buttonFn={(e) => playGame(e)} />;
}

function GameContainer({ buttonFn }) {
  return (
    <>
      <p>Game name</p>
      <ButtonContainer buttonFn={buttonFn} />
    </>
  );
}

function ButtonContainer({ buttonFn }) {
  return (
    <>
      <button id="btn-1" value="btn-1" onClick={buttonFn}>
        X
      </button>
      <button id="btn-2" value="btn-2" onClick={buttonFn}>
        Y
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/old-cloud-0deig?file=/src/App.js:51-592